# AWS API Gateway Authorizer always rejects Authorization Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am trying to only let users who are authorized via Cognito make requests to my lambda backend. So I created an Authorizer on my API Gateway that should only grant access to authorized users but currently, it is rejecting every request.
[image: Authorizer configuration]

Then I tried testing it but it always rejects the jwtToken I'm giving to it.
[image: Test]

I am sure that this jwtToken is valid and the user Account status is confirmed. I don't really have more information.
Thank you for reading this

Comment: Modify "Token Source" to `method.request.header.Authorization`? The console seems to be a bit broken for some inputs so maybe try setting it with the CLI instead.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include 'Bearer' in front of the TOKEN, e.g. `Bearer ey...`